# Ansible Timeout waiting for privilege escalation prompt when using ask-pass and ask-become-pass

Tags: ansible, timeout, sudo, privilege-elevation

We have a fairly restrictive procedure for creating new Centos 7 VMs on GCP.

- We create a VM from an image, then
- we log in with a so-called rescue user (let them be called `xyzRescue`) who has a very long password
- we `su` to `root` (`xyzRescue` does not have `sudo` rights), requiring another, different, very long password
- add an admin user and their SSH key and a `sudoers` entry for them

This works fine but is very slow.

I am trying to automate this with Ansible.

The attempt fails while gathering facts.

The command I use and its output is as follows

```
$ ansible-playbook -i new.hosts -u xyzRescue --become-user root --ask-pass --ask-become-pass --become-method=su sudoers.yml
SSH password: <entered xyzRescue's password>
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]: <entered root's password>

PLAY [Configure sudo rights] ***********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [avm-p]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

Timeout (62s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt:

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
avm-p                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The ansible playbook looks like this:

```
- name: Configure sudo rights
  hosts: new_hosts
  become: True
  become_method: su
  become_flags: "-"
  roles:
    - sudoers
```

I can't figure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?